# "failed to determine a suitable driver class" exception occured in configuring the hikaricp and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Configure the hikaricp using solely the *application.properties* file residing in the *resources* dir.

*application.properties* content:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/torquejobqa_db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.username=dev0
spring.datasource.hikari.password=123456
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
```

"build.gradle" content:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This is a general purpose Gradle build.
 * Learn how to create Gradle builds at https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds
 */
plugins {
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

bootWar {
    mainClassName = 'com.valuep.ccrlinsightor.Application'
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        /* need to exclude the embedded tomcat server, otherwise there will be a deploy error when deploying to the jetty server */
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    // use the embedded jetty server
    // providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    // implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.0.jre11'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'
}
```

Build the project into a war file and copy it into */webapps* in Jetty base dir.
when the Jetty deploy the war, an exception was thrown:

```
17:40:49.367 [Scanner-0] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.datasource.bean-class-loader]
17:40:49.368 [Scanner-0] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.datasource.bean-class-loader] threw NamingException with message: null. Returning null.
17:40:49.370 [Scanner-0] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'dataSource' via factory method to bean named 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties'
17:40:49.371 [Scanner-0] WARN org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
17:40:49.372 [Scanner-0] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
17:40:49.378 [Scanner-0] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileChanged(WebAppProvider.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:558)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
2020-08-18 17:40:49.378:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-0: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@28f709bc{ccrl-insightor,/ccrl-insightor,file:///tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-ccrl-insightor_war-_ccrl-insightor-any-9096073790800133207.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/dev0/jettybase/webapps/ccrl-insightor.war}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileChanged(WebAppProvider.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:558)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileChanged(WebAppProvider.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:558)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileChanged(WebAppProvider.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:558)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
    at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
```

I followed this [Spring Boot Features doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) ,[Hikaricp Configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) and get this exception. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you include the JDBC driver? Without it it won't work.

Comment: Could it be just a typo at your `build.gradle` at `implemetation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'` where it should be `implementation`? (there is a missing `n`).

Comment: sry,  i miss the n in the build.gradle file  :-P, but it still don't work :-(

Comment: try without `driver-class-name`

Answer (score 0):

sry, i didn't add some extra info to question description.
this is a web application running in the servlet container Jetty. this gradle project is aimed at packaging as a traditional deployable war file.

it seems that the `application.properties` file is not detected by Spring Boot at all.

solution:
I make my @SpringBootApplication annotated class extend the SpringBootServletInitializer according to the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file. the SpringBootServletInitializer will register the DispatcherServer and configure the root ApplicationContext for ContextLoaderListener.